# Call blocking with spoken message?

Tags: applications, call-screening

Does anyone know of a call blocker that will let you create a voice message for blocked calls?

What I want is to block calls from hidden numbers. This is almost always salespeople so I want to just block them, but maybe once in a while someone with no ill intent might be calling from a line with a hidden number.

So I want the app to actually take the call, but not tell me about it. Then it should play a sound file that I make and then hang up.

This will let me tell the person at the other end, that I just blocked them to get rid of salespeople and that if they are not such a "person" then they should just use SMS.

I know that some of the apps will let you type in a text that will be sent to blocked callers, but as it will almost never be a cellphone, but an old land line with blocked number, then that will not help a lot.

If no one knows of an app that will let me do this, then I will just have to make it my self, but I thought I'd better ask first.

Comment: ask your carrier? they may have call blocking service and voicemail service; they might be able to configure hidden numbers to go straight to voicemail.

Comment: nope, asked already. Besides, I don't want the calls to go to my normal voicemail, since it will not tell them why they got there and my carrier does not support multiple voicemails.

Comment: You might be able to do something with Google Voice. You can customize your outgoing message based on contacts or contact groups. You could make your default message the one for the people blocking their number.

Comment: sadly, no google voice. Not in the US :)

Comment: I, too, would LOVE an app (or anything else!) that would allow me to achieve this exact same thing.  To have my Android answer the call (without having alerted me in anyway) and simply play a pre-recorded message to the caller then hang-up.

Comment: No app can send audio to calls (A chip thing). It would only be doable by a voice mailbox

Answer (score 3):

I found one that does just this last week. Check out http://www.youmail.com. It's an app you download, but can manage it from their website. You can record different greetings for different people; family, business and the main reason I got it.... the number has been disconnected for people I REALLY don't want to talk to! I also have a msg just for Blocked Called IDs, telling them I dont accept them and to unblock their number. And...it's FREE :)

Comment: Looks like a great service, but only US so far. Or so it looks. Anyway it will not take my phone number as a valid one. So no support in my country anyway.

Comment: You might try Hullomail to see if it is available, as it has similar things. I don't know if you can direct callers on-the-fly, so to speak, though.

Comment: it's not free anymore ($5/mo)

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this - this is somewhat unheard of, block hidden numbers and load up a sound file and play it which defeats the purpose  of a number being blocked, in pseudo-code, for the most part of call-blocking apps, it would be something like this:

```
if incoming_number is on block_list
   send reject_call
else
   allow
```

Now, if what you're saying is this - to play a sound file, it would mean that the incoming blocked number would have the handset open in which Android **would** notify there's an incoming call, and re-route the playing of the sound file to the speaker, technically that's quite a difficult thing to do!

But, there is an [app](http://vmad.com/apps.html) to do something like what you're looking for - 'Private Stop' -

> No one likes getting "Private" or "Hidden" number calls, you can use
>   Private Stop to block nuisance callers, Marketeers, stalkers, anyone
>   that hides their number. Private Stop blocks the call and pushes the
>   caller to your voice mail so you can decide if you want to communicate
>   with the "Hidden" caller or not

Comment: As one commenter above, stated - _No app can send audio to calls (A chip thing)_ And why the downvote, because the OP clearly is asking for something technically impossible and pointed out an alternative. Still, no pleasing people as in "I WANT" stomping their feet off the ground like a 5 year old throwing a tantrum

Answer (score 0):

[Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) allows you to do this.

You can make up to four different answering-recordings and specify who gets directed to which one, and that the called automatically gets directed to voicemail, without ringing your phone.

You have to configure the settings at http://voice.google.com , but after that, the app will even give you a neat widget that transcribes your voicemails!

Comment: The OP pointed out in the comment above under Eliazara's answer that Google Voice is only for US only and OP is outside of US :)

Comment: -_- 
It's still a valuable answer to this question, isn't it? 
There may be some Americans asking the same question.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the only thing that blocks the call from coming through to your phone (you never know about it, it shows up nowhere) and gives a message to the caller who blocks their number stating that there is call restrictions is "Family Base" from Verizon, but it charges you $5/month. Yes, that is a bit much to spend monthly just to have this 'convenience', it seems to be the only way I can figure out how to take care of those calls.

I did use an app called "Call Filter". That app would not notify you of the attempted call, & what I liked was it just 'hung-up' & not go to voicemail. But, since I have a 'Jellybean' update, I guess the app does not support that yet, so I got a "free month 'trial'" of the 'Family Base' until I can either find an app that does not send call to voicemail, or the "Call Filter" app updates to support the 5.+ Jellybean update.

Hope this helps someone, but I can't give a definitive answer as to if it works outside the USA.

Comment: FYI, 5.+ is Lollipop, not JellyBean... or do you mean the app version? Anyway, could you provide a link of "Call Filter" on Play Store? Is it [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.telemarks.CallFilter2)? It seems more useful than Verizon/US-only solution for general users.