# Withheld, unknown or new number filtering - by asking caller to state their name

Tags: caller-id, call-screening

How can I make my phone do the following if the number is unknown:

- Answer the phone
- Play a message that says "As you are calling from an unknown number, please State your name"
- Record their reply
- Put them on hold
- Allow me to hear their message and either accept the call, send to voicemail or hang up

Comment: Generally app recommendations are considered off-topic here, you might want to edit your question along the lines of "how can I make my phone do..." rather than asking for an app.

Comment: Very similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/call-blocking-with-spoken-message

Comment: So, basically you want an answering machine type call screener app?

Answer (score 4):

[Google Voice](http://voice.google.com) has options for this.  If you have a Voice account and someone calls you using that number you can use the Call Screening option to force them to record a message you can hear before you pick up.

[image: GV Call Screening]

**Edit:** Google Voice is currently only available in the US, so if you live anywhere else this solution obviously won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing thru the market led me to this app called [Mr. Number](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker).

Features:

- NEW: Status for calls and texts
- Block calls and texts from one person or the world
- Automatic reverse lookup for every number that is not in your contacts
- Manual reverse lookup for mystery calls on your home or work phone
- Add new contacts to your address book with one click
- Catch telemarketers, debt collectors, and other spammers before they waste your time
- Report spam calls and texts to warn other users
- Control what name other Mr. Number users see when you call them